Homeomorphism to $[0,1]^n$ preserving equality of measure
Let $A\subseteq R^n$ be a subset which is homeomorphic to $\left[0,1\right]^n$. Does there exists a homeomorphic map $f:A\rightarrow \left[0,1\right]^n$ such that for any $X_1,X_2\subseteq\left[0,1\right]^n$ with $\mu(X_1)=\mu(X_2)$, $\mu(f^{-1}(X_1))=\mu(f^{-1}(X_2))$ holds? $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure.

Up to rescale we can suppose that $A$ has measure $1$, and then the condition means that $f$ is measure-preserving.

I am afraid that the answer to the question is negative for $n=2$ because the boundary of $A$ can have positive Lebesgue measure in the plane.

Examples for the comment of Taras Banakh are Oosgod curves (combined with the Schoenflies theorem).

More on Osgood curves here.

However this is true for open $A$ and open cube.
